# Factorization removed from variables with addition of new code

Tags: r

I am working on subsetting factorizing variables in a dataset. However, when I move on to a different variable, the factorization of the variable I just worked on seems to be removed. How do I write the code so that all of the variables are permanently factorized?

I created a test dataset to see if the problem was with the data I was working with, but the problem occurred in the test dataset as well:

[Code][1]

```
rTestDataSet = subset(TestDataSet, TestDataSet$Height < 5)
rTestDataSet$Height = as.factor(rTestDataSet$Height)
levels(rTestDataSet$Height) = c("Small", "Medium", "Large", "Massive")
summary(rTestDataSet$Height)
rTestDataSet = subset(TestDataSet, TestDataSet$Weight < 5)
summary(rTestDataSet$Height)
```

Comment: If you have code already as text, please copy-and-paste it here as text. An image is frustrating to work with as anyone trying to recreate the issue has to type it all out by hand.

Comment: In your second subset command, you subset the original `TestDataSet`, where the variables have not been changed, and overwrite `rTestDataSet`.